# Threejs - 3D rotate house with multiple image

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to use ThreeJs to get a 3D rotate building split in different image ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, Stephane. We're going to need more information than this. If you can provide pictures of the effect you're trying to accomplish, that would be helpful. Also, please remember to include what you've tried so far (including code). Stack Overflow isn't an on-demand coding service, but we will gladly help you with errors and problems you are encountering.

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for you comment, i know and totaly agree. The problem is i don't know, what i want to do is called, i just wanted to know how is it called ^^ or maybe what is the philosophy i have to understant behind what i would like :) I'm trying with mulitple image which composed a house with different angle (360) to make this house 3D and i can rotate, in fact i don't want code but juste advise on how is it possible to do this and what is the vocabulary :)

Comment: Taking multiple pictures and creating a 3D model is akin to 3D scanning, which is not something you'd want to do in the browser (it uses process-intensive techniques like edge detection and spatial mapping). Google Maps does that, but the geometry isn't constructed at runtime. This question might be better suited for [`computer-vision`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-vision), [`image-processing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/image-processing), or [`machine-learning`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning), not `three.js`/`javascript`.

Comment: Ok i understand more further now :) Thanks i'm going to check all this